# Where is the data stored for custom fields in WooCommerce/Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-hook

I have a plugin that adds custom fields to the WooCommerce account page. Take the apikey field below as an example (this is just a random field, it could be anything)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'add_api_info_to_account_form' );
function add_api_info_to_account_form() {
  $user = wp_get_current_user();
  ?>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><?php esc_html_e( 'GHL/MBO Sync', 'woocommerce' ); ?></legend>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="apikey"><?php _e( 'MBO API Key', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" 
         name="apikey" id="apikey" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->apikey ); ?>" />
    </p>
```

Whenever I go to the profile page, I see that the value $user->apikey is loaded from **wp_get_current_user()**

However, in my other file, I'm trying to access every user's API key using **get_users()**, and the apikey information is not returned.

Is there a way to return custom fields like this with an array of all users?

Here's the code from the second file:

```
$users = get_users();
print_r($users);
```

it returns a big array, but no apikey field

Comment: get_users() does not return a user options, custom fields or any data expect the code information of a user. check more on this FN: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow, TO load a user meta (custom field) you need ot use this function get_user_meta($user_id, $meta_key ).

So to put it simple, to get the user API key to use this line

```
global $current_user; 
$user_api_key = get_user_meta($current_user->id, 'apikey' );
```

You can place $user_api_key anywhere you want to display the apikey.
Please try this out and let me know if it works for you. I'm here to help.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress uses the wp_users table to store user data in its database. Only the most basic user information is stored in wp_users table. It includes just the username (user_login), password (user_pass) and email (user_email) of each user. In order to store additional user data, the wp_usermeta table is used. The ID field from the users table and the user_id field from wp_usermeta table are used to link the record of the same user.
To retrieve user meta you can use the get_user_meta function.

For more details please review the WordPress documentation https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/